# How to fix vulnerable issue in codeigniter?(Privilege Escalation, Session Replay Attack and HSTS Missing)

Tags: php, codeigniter-3, burp

I have codeigniter web apllication. i am facing some security issues when i am scanning application with burp-suite.Can you tell me to fix following security issues.

**The issues are :**

1. **Non-randomized CSRF Token -**
   It is recommended to generate random token that is unique per user session, large random value, and also
   generated by a cryptographically secure random number generator.
2. **Vulnerable to Cross-Site Request Forgery Attack -**
   It is recommended to use Token Based Mitigation; by implementing Synchronizer token pattern in html requests
3. **Privilege Escalation -**
   It is recommended that the sessions are handled properly where a normal user cannot visit a restricted URL
4. **Session Replay Attack -**
   It is recommended to develop session handling methodologies to make sure that a user session ends upon the termination of the browser
5. **Cookie without HTTP Flag only set**
6. **Secure communication enforcing is not enabled. (HSTS Missing From HTTPS Server)**

My `login.php`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){ 
        $.ajaxSetup({
            data: {
                '<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_token_name(); ?>' : '<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_hash(); ?>'
            }
        });
    });
</script>
    <form>
    <input type="hidden" name="<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_token_name(); ?>" value="<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_hash(); ?>" />
    <input autocorrect="off" maxlength="50"  autocapitalize="off" autocomplete="off"  name='email' id='email' type='text' />
    <input name='current_url' id='current_url' value="<?php echo $current_url; ?>" type='hidden'/>
    <input name='password' id='password' maxlength="50" type='password' autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" autocomplete="off" />
    <input type="submit"  value="Login"   name="btnsubmit" />
      </form>
```

This is my config.php

```
$config['csrf_protection'] = TRUE;
$config['csrf_token_name'] = 'csrf_token_myapp';
$config['csrf_cookie_name'] = 'csrf_cookie_myapp';
$config['csrf_expire'] = 1200;
$config['csrf_regenerate'] = TRUE;

$config['cookie_prefix']    = 'myweb_c_';
$config['cookie_domain']    = '';
$config['cookie_path']      = '/';
$config['cookie_secure']    = FALSE;
$config['cookie_httponly']  = TRUE;

$config['sess_driver'] = 'files';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'pay_web';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 900;
$config['sess_save_path'] = '\\storage\\'
$config['sess_match_ip'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 60;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = TRUE;

$config['charset'] = 'UTF-8';
$config['enable_hooks'] = FALSE;
$config['cache_query_string'] = FALSE;
$config['encryption_key'] = 'MKNNWNnsanas^@&#(@(*88899';
$config['composer_autoload'] = FALSE;
```

I need to encrypt current url, username and password. following line i am getting from burp-suite. 
`csrf_token_myapp=3d44fd27c845cf3eb8cb521233c52150&csrf_token_myapp=3d44fd27c845cf3eb8cb521233c52150&email=admin%40test.lk&current_url=&password=test1234567&btnsubmit=Login`

Comment: Are you looking for a solution to encrypt the data from the front-end, send it to the server and decrypt from PHP server-side so in the middle layer the data is not visible?

Comment: Yes, i need to encrypt form data in front-end side and decrypt in server side.

Comment: What is the suitable encryption method you are looking for?

Comment: i tried AES encryption method.

Comment: the form perfoms a GET request instead of a POST. this way, the credentials are leaked into server logs, are visible in browser URL and the usage of csrf is pointless (as CSRF validation only works for POST requests)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usage of the expected method is to encrypt the value of the front-end form and send it to the server, then it should be decrypted from the server-side using PHP. The middle layers can see the submitted result as an encrypted value.

**Encryption:** Using `AES` from `CryptoJS` (In browser):

```js
(function() {
  var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt("I am a hacker", "MYKEY");
  console.log(encrypted.toString());
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/3.1.2/rollups/aes.js"></script>
```

---

**Decryption:** Using `aes-256-cbc` from `openssl_decrypt` (In PHP):

```
<?php

function decryptAES($edata, $password)
{
    $data = base64_decode($edata);
    $salt = substr($data, 8, 8);
    $ct = substr($data, 16);
    $rounds = 3;
    $data00 = $password . $salt;
    $md5_hash = array();
    $md5_hash[0] = md5($data00, true);
    $result = $md5_hash[0];

    for ($i = 1; $i < $rounds; $i++) {
        $md5_hash[$i] = md5($md5_hash[$i - 1] . $data00, true);
        $result .= $md5_hash[$i];
    }

    $key = substr($result, 0, 32);
    $iv  = substr($result, 32, 16);
    $decrypted = openssl_decrypt($ct, 'aes-256-cbc', $key, true, $iv);
    return $decrypted;
}


$password = 'MYKEY';
$edata = 'U2FsdGVkX1+H/Mqv5QgZzAHAXdoGVE1kY9uyfYJKbaA=';

echo decryptAES($edata, $password) . "\n";
// Output - I am a hacker
```

---

> This encryption way is not a perfect way to encrypt form data since you store the secret key at the front-end side which can be decrypted over the browser developer tools. The best way is to focus on strong security validations from your server-side.

Comment: Thank you @Googlian. This code helped me to fix 'Vulnerable to Cross-Site Request Forgery Attack' issue.